# Why do I get an Unknown Primary Key exception for a join table in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, join

These are my models:

```
class Product
  has_many :line_items
  has_many :orders, :through => :line_items
end

class LineItem 
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Order
    has_many :line_items
    has_many :products, :through => :line_items
end
```

From schema.rb:

```
  create_table "line_items", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

I just upgraded to Rails 4, and my join table stopped working. If I do `@order.line_items`, it throws the exception "Unknown primary key for table line_items in model LineItem." `@order.products` works as expected.

I have tried dropping and recreating the line_items table, and I have tried installing the protected_attributes gem, but nothing changed.

Here is [the trace](http://pastebin.com/Z5BDBFEY).

Comment: Because there's no primary key? ;) I think you need t ocreate migration with something like `add_index :line_items, [:order_id, :product_id], primary: true`

Comment: I should have mentioned, my original table had "add_index "line_items", ["order_id", "product_id"]" but I didn't use that when I tried dropping and recreating the table. I tried running a migration just now with the "primary: true" but it said that it doesn't recognize the keyword "primary." I can't find anything about this "primary" option in the docs for add_index.

Comment: I guessed it should be primary, no idea really how to add non-default primary index via rails. Let me google a little

Comment: "By default, create_table will create a primary key called id. You can change the name of the primary key with the :primary_key option (don't forget to update the corresponding model)" so maybe it would be `add_index :line_items, [:order_id, :product_id], primary_key: true`

Comment: Looks like possibility to add a primary_key exista only when creting a table - strange. Could you try adding a regular index and in model setting `self.primary_key = [:order_id, :product_id]`?

Comment: Or maybe `add_index(:table, [:col1, :col2], type: :primary)`?

Comment: According to the docs, :primary_key sets the name of the key. It's not a boolean for determining whether or not a primary key exists, since it is supposed to always exist anyway.

Comment: You can create a table without primary key, models just don't detect it and assume its :id unless you specify different one (or false for none). See my comments, one of them may help.

Comment: @Michael Szyndel `self.primary_key = [:order_id, :product_id]` in the model solves it! Thank you! If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it accepted. And if you or anyone else could give insight as to why that's suddenly necessary in Rails 4, please do.

Comment: In guides for Rails 4 it is stated that model is not guessing the primary key. Maybe they changed it from Rails 3? Would be great if I were so good with Rails to know it :D

Comment: Also similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/26763969/988591

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In model add the following:

```
self.primary_key = [:order_id, :product_id]
```

and I think it would be wise to ensure that there's an `index` on those columns.

You may create one with following migration:

```
add_index :line_items, [:order_id, :product_id]
```

Comment: This is not the right answer! The `self.primary_key = [:order_id, :product_id]` line is wrong and as @Iala noted in his own answer, it will give errors because Active Record does not support composite primary keys. There is a gem if you want to add support for this https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

Comment: @jj_ I'm pretty confident this worked over a year ago. Also what OP says is that it actually worked but probably Rails requires an index on those columns.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a0dfd84440f28d2862b7eb7ea340ca28d98fb23f/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb#L115

Comment: Also take a look at my own question and own answer for a similar case http://stackoverflow.com/a/26772047/988591

Comment: Ok, I even double check and you are right. Makes me wonder how SO uproots work, no one released this was wrong?

Answer (score 8):

The `id: false` in your original schema indicates that there is no `id` field in the table. Rails 4 added a `create_join_table` helper method which creates tables with no `id` field and uses this for any migration with `JoinTable` in the name.

The only way I can imagine that you're getting difference results with Rails 4 than with Rails 3 is if you regenerated your migrations and had a migration with `JoinTable` in the name. Do you still have your schema from Rails 3 around? It would be interesting to note it has `id: false` for the join table.

As for the primary_key, the reason you could set the primary key to an array but it subsequently didn't work  is because the `primary_key=` method blindly converts its argument to a string per line 115 of https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a0dfd84440f28d2862b7eb7ea340ca28d98fb23f/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb#L115

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016034/1008891 and its links.

Answer (score 4):

Removing the `id: false` should fix your error. 
To do that, make a migration with the following line:

`add_column :model, :id, :primary_key`

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer got rid of the error message, but I was still unable to save @order.line_items without getting an error telling me [:order_id, :product_id] does not exist.

I finally solved this by deleting the line_items table and recreating it with this migration:

```
  def change
    create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.references :order
      t.references :product
      t.integer :quantity
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I hadn't used "references" when I created the table originally, which Rails 3 didn't mind, but made Rails 4 complain.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, but dropping my local database with `rake db:drop` and then creating with `rake db:create` before running `pg_restore` with the heroku db dump solved it.

Comment: Same problem with me in Heroku with Sidekiq worker. I restarted all the dyno and is working fine.