# Weird error with has_and_belongs_to_many PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column articles.article_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have defined two models, an they both refer to each other with has_and_belongs_to_many

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

I have one migration added:

```
class CreateJoinTableArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :articles, :categories do |t|
      t.index [:article_id, :category_id]
      t.index [:category_id, :article_id]
    end
  end
end
```

And I get this weird error when trying to edit an article in rails admin http://localhost:3000/admin/article/20/edit

```
    Showing /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rails_admin-0.7.0/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_filtering_multiselect.html.haml where line #10 raised:

    PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column articles.article_id does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class CreateJoinTableArticleCategory < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :articles, :categories do |t|
      t.index :article_id
      t.index :category_id
    end
  end
end
```

Ref: [api doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table)

Edit: **No need to add index and primary key into join table.**

Ref: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016034/2681997)

Comment: I think problem in somewhere else. Notice the error is about articles.article_id column.

Comment: @n1ckbren: Please add `admin/article/:id/edit` page form_helper view code into question. And you are right error is something else.