# How to stop rails from calling next_seq for a join table without id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, firebird

I'm working with Rails 3.2.13 and fb-adapter (firebird, but I don't believe that to be relevant here).

I have a join model that other two model use with "has_many A, through: X".

I've created the table without an "id" (acording to rails guides, and common sense because the pk is a combination of the two) like this:

```
create table "X", id: false do |t|
  t.integer "a_id", null: false
  t.integer "b_id", null: false
end
```

Then when I've tried to create a model and I got "ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey"; ok I had googled and I've found [Why do I get an Unknown Primary Key exception for a join table in Rails 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17630714/why-do-i-get-an-unknown-primary-key-exception-for-a-join-table-in-rails-4)

So in the join Model I've set:

```
class X < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = [:a_id, :b_id]
  ...
end
```

Now I can create a new model, but when I try to save it I run into "Fb::Error: Invalid token 
generator X_SEQ is not defined", so basically rails is trying to get the next value for the id, but because the column wasn't created the generator or sequence for it neither.

Here is the relevant code in activerecord/relation.rb:

```
def insert(values)
  primary_key_value = nil

  if primary_key && Hash === values
    primary_key_value = values[values.keys.find { |k|
      k.name == primary_key
    }]

    if !primary_key_value && connection.prefetch_primary_key?(klass.table_name)
      ### exception get's raised here in next_sequence_value ###
      primary_key_value = connection.next_sequence_value(klass.sequence_name)
      values[klass.arel_table[klass.primary_key]] = primary_key_value
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

I don't know if this happens also with the sqlite3 / mysql / postegres adapters, but I believe that if the PK is compound rails should not try to get a "next value for it".. or there must be some way to prevent it from trying to get the next value.. Any ideas how to solve this (without patching activerecord)? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For pure many-to-many relationships, use [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) relationships in your models. No model is needed for your join table. Use [has_many](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) :through relationships where additional data (such as a sort order or timestamps) is needed in your join table. In such a case, a full-fledged model would be appropriate and models require a primary key.

Comment: My model has other data, what I've presented here is a simplification that focuses on the problem.. I've read the rails guide again and it looks like you are right the guide suggests using "id: false" only in the subsection of HABTM.. it doesn't makes full sense to me, but it looks like that's the "rails way" because it doesn't supports compound pk.