# Accessing a join-model attribute stored in a join table created with #create_join_table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, nested-attributes

In a Rails ( 4.1.5 / ruby 2.0.0p481 / win64 ) application I have a many-to-many relationship between Student and Course and a join model StudentCourse which represents the association, which has an additional attribute called "started", which is set by default on "false".

I also have added an index in the join table made of the student_id and the course_id, and set a unique check on that, like this

```
t.index [:student_id, :course_id], :unique => true, :name => 'by_student_and_course'
```

Now I see that associations are created by either doing:

```
Student.first.courses.create(:name => "english")
```

or

```
Course.first.students << Student.first
```

This is fine and it's the expected behaviour, I suppose.

**What I am looking after is the correct way to get and set the "started" attribute.**
I am seeing an odd behaviour when accessing that attribute from the other models and not straight from the join model.

```
s = Student.create
c = Course.create(:name => "english")

s.student_courses.first
```

=> | "english" | false |  # (represented as a table for practicity)

```
s.student_courses.first.started = true
```

=> | "english" | true |

```
s.save
```

=> true

Ok this looks like it has been saved but when I loot ak:

```
StudentCourse.first
```

=> | 1 | 1 | false |

So it is set on true if I go through the student nested attributes, but it's still false in the join model. I also tried doing "reload!" but it makes no difference and they will mantaint their own different value.

**If something is going so bad that values are not actually persisted I should be told instead of getting "true" when saving, because otherwise how bad could be the consequences of this ? What am I missing here?**

Anyway, if I try modifying the "started" attribute on the join model directly, I meet another kind of problem:

```
StudentCourse.first.started = true
```

StudentCourse Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "student_courses".* FROM "student_courses"  LIMIT 1
=> true

```
StudentCourse.first.started
```

=> false

It has not changed!

```
StudentCourse.find_by(:student_id => "10", :course_id => "1").started = true
```

=> true

```
StudentCourse.find_by(:student_id => "10", :course_id => "1").started
```

=> false

Same as before.. I try with:

```
StudentCourse.find(1).started = true
```

ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table student_courses in model StudentCourse.

Then with:

```
sc = StudentCourse.first
sc.started = true
```

=> true

```
sc
```

=> | 1 | 1 | true |

seems great but when saving:

```
sc.save
```

> (0.0ms)  begin transaction
>
> SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "student_courses" SET "started" = ? WHERE
>   "student_courses"."" IS NULL  [["started", "true"]]
>   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student_courses.: UPDATE
>   "student_courses" SET "started" = ? WHERE "student_courses"."" IS NULL
>   (1.0ms)  rollback transaction ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student_courses.: UPDATE
>   "student_courses" SET "started" = ? WHERE "student_courses"."" IS
>   NULL from
>   C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `initialize'

- So I think this all has to do with not having a primary key in
  join-table?
- But I am not sure enough on how to use it and if that'd represent a
  good practice for the case I am trying to solve ?
- Also, if this is the problem, why then I don't get the same warning
  here when I save the student after I do
  `s.student_courses.first.started = true`, as shown in the examples
  above?

#### Code

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :student_courses
  has_many :courses, :through => :student_courses

end
```

**course.rb**

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :student_courses
  has_many :students, :through => :student_courses
end
```

**student_course.rb**

```
class StudentCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141020135702) do

  create_table "student_courses", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "course_id",    null: false
    t.integer "student_id",   null: false
    t.string  "started",      limit: 8, default: "pending", null: false
  end

  add_index "student_courses", ["course_id", "student_id"], name: "by_course_and_student", unique: true

  create_table "courses", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",        limit: 50, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "students", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",        limit: 50, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

**create_join_table.rb (migration for join table)**

```
class CreateJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :courses, :students, table_name: :student_courses do |t|
      t.index [:course_id, :student_id], :unique => true, :name => 'by_course_and_student'       
      t.boolean :started, :null => false, :default => false 
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Please list your model definitions of Student, Class and StudentClass.

Comment: @nikkon226 updated question with code

Comment: Is the StudentCourse schema `id, course_id, student_id, started, created_at, updated_at`?

Comment: added to question schema.rb and migration code for join table creation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I finally got what was going on here:

If you create a join table in a migration using `#create_join_table`, this method will **not** create the default primary key called "id" (and not add an index for it) which is what rails does by default when using `#create_table`.

ActiveRecord needs a primary key to build its queries, because it is the column that it will be used by default when doing things like `Model.find(3)`.

Also if you think you can get around this by doing something like `StudentCourse.find_by(:course_id => "1", :student_id => "2").update_attributes(:started => true)` **[0]** it will still fail, because after the record it's found, AR will still try to update it looking at the "id" of the record it found.

Also `StudentCourse.find_by(:course_id => "1", :student_id => "2").started = true` will retrun true but of course it is not saved until you call #save on it. If you assign it to a var `relationship` and then you call `relationship.save` you will see it will fail to save for the above reasons.

---

**[0]**
In the join table I didn't want duplicate records for a "student_id" and "course_id" so in the migration I had explicitely added a unique constraint for them (using unique index).

This led me to think that I did not need anymore a primary key to uniquely identify a record, because I had those two values... I thought that adding an index on them was enough for they to work as a primary key... but it is not. You need to explicitely define a primary-key when you are not using the default "id" one.

Also turns out that **Rails does not support composite primary keys** and so even if I wanted to add a primary key build on those two values (so making them primary-key and unique-index, like default rails "id" works) it would have not been possible.

A gem for that exists: https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

---

So, end of the story, **the way I fixed it** was simply adding `t.column :id, :primary_key` to the migration for the join table creation. Also I could have not created the join table with `#create_join_table` but instead using just `#create_table` (which would create an "id" automatically").

Hope this helps someone else.

Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20016157/988591) answer to another question was very helpful, thank you @Peter Alfvin !

Comment: This did help someone... me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, it appears that you don't have a primary key (we are getting confirmation shortly) in your join table. You do need to have a primary key when trying to access the join table.

I would suggest your migration be:

```
class CreateStudentCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :student_courses do |t|
      t.references :course
      t.references :student
      t.boolean :started, default: false

      t.timestamps

      t.index [:student_id, :course_id], :unique => true, :name => 'by_student_and_course'
    end
  end
end
```

The model definitions look good, so that would be the only change I can see that needs to be made.

After that, doing what you have been doing should work correctly. You would create the join and then access it after the creation. If you want to assign the boolean to true upon creation, you would need to create the record through the `StudentCourse` model with the information you need (student_id, course_id and started = true) instead of through either association.

```
StudentCourse.create(course_id: course.id, student_id: student.id, started: true)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
s = Student.create
c = Course.create(:name => "english")
s.student_courses.first.started = true
s.save
```

I think the clue here is in the first line that you posted (represented above).  s is an instance of the student and when you call s.save then you're asking the student to save any changes to its attributes.  There are not any changes to save, however, because you made a change to an association.

You have a couple of options.  If you prefer the direct access approach from your code snippet then the following should work.

```
s = Student.create
c = Course.create(:name => 'english')
s.courses << c
s.student_courses.first.update_attributes(:started => true)
```

Another alternative would be to use the accepts_nested_attributes_for macro to expose the started attribute from the student perspective.

```
class Student
  has_many :student_courses, :inverse_of => :student
  has_many :courses,         :through => :student_courses

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student_courses
end

s = Student.create
c = Course.create(:name => 'english')
s.courses << c
s.update_attributes(:student_courses_attributes=>[{:id => 1, :started => true}])
```

Comment: > s.student_classes.first.update_attributes(:started => true)

   `(0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.0ms)  UPDATE "student_courses" SET "activated" = ? WHERE "student_courses"."" IS NULL  [["started", "t"]] SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student_courses.: UPDATE "student_courses" SET "activated" = ? WHERE "student_courses"."" IS NULL
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: student_courses.: UPDATE "student_courses" SET "started" = ? WHERE "student_courses"."" IS NULL`
from .../lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'

Comment: It's not that I prefer one or the other method ( 1 - setting the attribute on the join model instance directly vs 2 - accessing it from a model instance nested attributes). 

I am trying to understand how this all works and the reason I am seeing the errors I see.
Are you sure that "accept_nested_attributes_for" is required? Shouldn't model nestings be implicit in declaring the relationships with "has_many ... :through" and "belongs_to" ?

Comment: As I thought it was not about nested attributes access not being allowed by "accept_nested_attributes_for". The error I pasted in the comment above shows that ActiveRecord tries to construct a query looking for the attribute column name like this `WHERE "student_courses".""`. Those last 2 double quotes are empty, because a the primary key "id" key that rails uses by default to identify a record has not been set because of the #create_join_table method in the migration does not create it.

Comment: Sorry, the details have changed so much here it's hard to keep up.

Comment: So much? I just switched the model name from "Class" to "Course" to avoid confusion.

Comment: Yes, the contents of the question changed considerably after I posted, including the names of attributes, presentation of the schema, etc.  Glad you worked out a viable solution.

Comment: Names have nothing to do with the real issue. Also, as you know, I've personally edited your answer with the new names to avoid you further headaches. Schema did not change, I've just uploaded the code for it. You suggested using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` which would have put me further off track in identifying what the real problem was. Nonetheless I appreciate your time and effort anyway as it still was an input for reasoning. Thanks for this!